# Product Import Error Magento 2.2.0

Tags: magento2.2.0

[image]

while importing product csv validation is done after clicking on import getting below error.

Answer (score 1):

this error comes when any **duplicate URL key is found in CSV or in the url_wrtite** table.
try to import product without url_key and once all products are imported then after import url_key.

Comment: Please mark my answare as right answare, So it will help to someone also